# GUI not working in Ubuntu 11.04 after removing some packages

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, gui, libraries

I accidentally removed `i32-libs` using the following command

```
      sudo apt-get remove ia32-libs
```

Now the GUI is not working properly: when I login, it just shows me a small terminal on one side of the screen, and nothing on the rest of the desktop. I ran

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

and I tried choosing a different session type on the login screen; if I select “Ubuntu classic mode” the desktop is fine but some applications still fail; for example when I start Skype, I see the message

```
skype: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`?

Comment: @pbm did this... gui is still bad

Comment: What is exactly wrong? Could you post screenshot?

Comment: @pbm tried that... cant get it nothing is working...

Comment: I did sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop... after that it shows me the lastest gui login... when I login it just shows me a small terminal on one side of the screen and nothing and rest id the desktop with nothing on it

Comment: I am starting this firefox from command line

Comment: Check if there is button/menu on login screen to choose session type. If there is change session type to Gnome or something else.

Comment: @pbm I did that... i logged in with the ubuntu classic mode... It looked fine untill I started first application... gui again messed up--- one message while starting skype was ---------  skype: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 perhaps this can help

Comment: You're still missing some packages. What does `dpkg -l libx11\*` show (run this command in a terminal)? What about `file /usr/lib*/libXss.*`?

Comment: /usr/lib*/libXss.*: ERROR: cannot open `/usr/lib*/libXss.*' (No such file or directory)

Comment: Were other packages removed when you removed `ia32-libs`? Check your logs. E.g. `/var/log/apt/history.log.*` and `/var/log/apt/term.log.*`

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the skype error, it is expecting a 32-bit library but only found a 64-bit one.
iirc ia32-libs is a package containing 32-bit libraries needed for running 32-bit programs in a 64-bit environment.
Since you accidentally removed it, i would just reinstall ia32-libs to try to resolve that error.